# Java How does this interface code actually work?

Tags: java

I've put together the code below using ideas giving to me by fellow members and then changing a couple of the containers. For the life of me i cant really get my head around some of this. The reason for the code is that i wished to pass a function as a parameter. The part of code i especially don't understand is:

```
doFunc(numbers, new IFunction() { 
    public void execute(Object o) { 
       Integer anInt = (Integer) o; 
       anInt++;
       System.out.println(anInt);
    } 
});
```

I understand to some extent that we're using an interface to represent a function using an object (i think?). This is the full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] strArray = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5};

    List numbers = Arrays.asList(strArray);
    doFunc(numbers, new IFunction() { 
        public void execute(Object o) { 
           Integer anInt = (Integer) o; 
           anInt++;
           System.out.println(anInt);
        } 
    }); 
    for(int y =0; y<numbers.size();y++){
        System.out.println(numbers.get(y));
    }
}

public static void doFunc(List c, IFunction f) { 
   for (Object o : c) { 
      f.execute(o); 
   } 
}

public interface IFunction { 
    public void execute(Object o); 
}
```

I guess i just need someone to go a little slower explaining it. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: I suggest you try stepping through the code in your debugger to see what each line of code does. Using Generics would make this code clearer IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main concept here is that since the second object you're passing to `doFunc` is **anonymous**, you don't need to instantiate an object here - just the interface. Here's what each part of the code is saying:

```
public interface IFunction { 
    public void execute(Object o); 
}
```

This says that any object which implements the interface `IFunction` has one method, `execute`, which it runs on another Object.

```
public static void doFunc(List c, IFunction f) { 
   for (Object o : c) { 
      f.execute(o); 
   } 
}
```

This function takes a List `c` and *any Object which implements IFunction*, then runs the `execute` method - guaranteed to be in the second object by the IFunction interface - over all the objects in `c`.

```
    doFunc(numbers, new IFunction() { 
        public void execute(Object o) { 
           Integer anInt = (Integer) o; 
           anInt++;
           System.out.println(anInt);
        } 
    });
```

This snippet from `main` takes a list of numbers and creates an *anonymous object* in-place which implements the IFunction interface. Since it's not any concrete object type, it doesn't need to have any other methods, just `execute`, which it defines inline.

The end result is that your IFunction object declared inside the call to `doFunc` is effectively a *functor* - it's a throwaway object that encapsulates a function, which can be run over a list of objects.

Comment: Am i right in thinking that when you said 'any object which implements the interface IFunction has one method', we dont use the keyword 'implements' here- so is implementation done by default when we create the 'new' object IFunction?

Comment: Correct - since you declare the object as a `new IFunction()`, the `implements` is implicit. Try this: if you're using Eclipse or another comparable IDE, comment out the definition of `execute` inside the `new IFunction() {...}` block, and your IDE should yell at you for "not providing implementations for all functions in the interface IFunction."

Answer (score 5):

That's an anonymous inner class. You could do as good as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] strArray = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5};

    List numbers = Arrays.asList(strArray);
    doFunc(numbers, new ConcreteFunction()); 
    for(int y =0; y<numbers.size();y++){
        System.out.println(numbers.get(y));
    }
}

public static void doFunc(List c, IFunction f) { 
   for (Object o : c) { 
      f.execute(o); 
   } 
}

public interface IFunction { 
    public void execute(Object o); 
} 

public class ConcreteFunction implements IFunction {
    public void execute(Object o) { 
       Integer anInt = (Integer) o; 
       anInt++;
       System.out.println(anInt);
    } 
}
```

The difference is that a concrete class is reuseable while an anonymous inner class is not.

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - Inner classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

IFunction, in this case, specifies an interface that anyone who implements the interface must define.

`public void execute(Object o);`

This means that any object that is an IFunction has this method.  The anonymous IFunction being defined in your example casts it's argument to an integer and then increments it and prints the value.

As doFunc requires a List of objects and an object that implements IFunction, the call in main passes `numbers`, a list of numbers, and the anonymous IFunction which increments them and prints their value.

doFunc then takes these objects in the list and passes them as an argument to the IFunction f.